# Can't modify Application Controller for 'hello world' app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've stumbled at Chp 1, Listing 1.8 of Hartl's tutorial.

The goal is to place a `hello` action into the Application controller.

This is supposed to happen:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

  def hello
    render text: "hello, world!"
  end
end
```

Instead, when I put in the first line

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

I get this:

`bash: ActionController::Base: No such file or directory`

**What I've done:**

I know the Application controller exists because `$ ls app/controllers/*_controller.rb` returns the Application controller file.

Other questions I've found on controllers concern topics such as SecurityMethods which I haven't seen mentioned so far.

I also tried just inputting `class ApplicationController` and was told `bash: class: command not found`.

Q: Am I supposed to have an `ActionController::Base` before taking this step?

Comment: Are  you just typing this into the command line?

Comment: @BradWerth is right, you're typing directly in command line (`bash`). Run the Rails console : `rails console` (rails >=3) or `script/console` (rails < 3) to run your commands.

Comment: Ok. So I ran `rails console` and the command line became this `2.1.5 :001 >`. I input `'class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base'` which results in `=> "class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base" `. Not as expected. Tried going on with the next command `def hello`, which resulted in a confused `12.1.5 :003?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you typing `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base` into the console?

What you are supposed to do is find your *sample_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb* and add the new text inside that file. Then save and close the file.