# Hello Action into App controller... Hartl tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am starting out Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I am stuck on Listing 1.8 which prompts the user to accomplish this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def hello
render text: "hello, world!"


 end
end
```

I have seen another post asking exactly the same question but the answer still didn't register to me. I went through the same process/mistakes. [Can't modify Application Controller for 'hello world' app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907915/cant-modify-application-controller-for-hello-world-app)

After all is said and done I don't understand this answer:

"What you are supposed to do is find your sample_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb and add the new text inside that file. Then save and close the file." How do I do this?

This was the satisfactory answer for that thread but I am still confused. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, you can't locate the correct file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer in the link you provided and having a look at the tutorial this is what you should do in a simpler way:

You know all the folders and files that make up your Rails app? You need to find the file named 'application_controller.rb'.

1. Open the folder called 'app'.
2. Once you're in the folder 'app', open the folder 'controllers'.
3. There you will find a file named 'application_controller.rb'. Open this file and add the text (highlighted by listing 1.8) to the file.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I got it to work. This is just the clear and concise explanation I needed. I just started learning last week so I didn't even realize the directions were referring to a folder. You saved the day, thanks again :)